# How to handle uncaught exceptions in Spring boot async function?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, exception

The async function, in case of any uncaught exception stops without throwing out any lines of error on the console.
If the function is not marked async, then the logs corresponding to it are printed.

```
@Async  
public CompletableFuture<?> AsyncManager() {
    logger.info("Executing method asynchronously - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.get("Hello").length();

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(map); 
  }
```

The above code is a snippet. I understand that it will throw null pointer exception and i have deliberately set it up that way.

> ERROR -Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context
>   with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null

When the function is marked @Async it shows nothing at the line i.e

```
map.get("Hello").length();
```

I understand that this might be because the exceptions are not propagated to the main thread. How do i handle the exceptions in async functions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put the whole code in try and catch(Exception ex) and log the exception.